# Unsubscribe to timer not possible if component destroyed quickly

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a component that make a loop api calls using rxjs `timer` operator

My problem is that if the component get destroyed ( for example close the modal ) within 5 seconds I get a loop calls seconds after ( May be the timer get not unsubscribed because it does not return yet a subscription )

What I would like to do is that timer does not make loop calls if I destroy component within 5 seconds.

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/CurrentRuns/currentruns.component.html'
})
export class CurrentRunsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    // Subscription object
    private sub: Subscription;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub= timer(firstcheckVal, 2500)
          .pipe(switchMap(() => this.testService.getTestdata())).subscribe(data => {
             ...
          }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        console.log("Destroy timer");
        // unsubscribe here
        if (this.sub) {
          this.sub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you internally do a check to see if the element exists?  That's pretty trivial.

Comment: The subscription object exists only in the component. I don't think that it's a good practice to access to it from another component ( And I should also verify if the modal containing the coimponent is closed to unsubscribe ). I prefer not also put the subscription in a global service the app is already complex.
I thought that there is a way to "cancel" timer on component destruction.

Comment: If you unsubscribe then the timer stops. If that's not happening please create a [mcve] to show the full functionality.

Comment: When I breakpoint on `onDestroy` within 5 seconds I see that sub is undefined yet.

Answer (score 1):

First declare the timer subscription like this:

```
private timer: Subscription;
```

And then, in `ngOnDestroy` you need to unsubscribe to timer subscription:

```
 this.timer.unsubscribe();
```

For reference, check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-pfbcak?file=src/app/app.component.ts), the timer will emit the first value after2.5 sec and then subsequently after 5 secs, but I am unsubscribing after 1 sec so there won;t be any value emitted by timer.

So at least one emission of timer will depend on the value of `firstcheckVal`. Check the timer [API](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer)

Comment: Sorry I was copying wrong code I have updated my snippet , You can then update your answer

Answer (score 0):

As a standard practice, within your component, add

```
private destroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.destroy$) {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about references to subscriptions or unsubscribing because at the end of your pipe you can add `takeUntil(this.destroy$)`

If you have another observable, same thing. They can all takeUntil(this.destroy$) and they'll automatically be closed and completed without having to make sure you unsubscribe.